# How to modify the circuit to drive the input pin low instead of high

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, short-circuit

I am using a pre-existing circuit and it is wired as the picture below to fix the high input to RAMN. I want to drive RAMN pin low to stall the booting. Can I just use the pad of C123 and short it to ground? Are there any other considerations?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I do not see why you need a capacitor at all. It only stabilizes whatever voltage is on the pin. And it has nothing to do with whether the resistor is there or not. I also do not see why you need a pull-up resistor when you want to drive the pin LO. If you want to drive it LO permanently then just connect it straight to GND. To be honest, I don't know what it is you are trying to do. Not enough context.

Comment: It might depend what RAMN pin is and what does it do. Besides it reads DNL next to cap which might mean it is not present in the actual circuit.

Comment: I think @DKNguyen last sentence describes it best:  "To be honest, I don't know what it is you are trying to do. Not enough context. – "

Comment: What do you mean when you say "*At the moment, RAMN is driven high"*. What is driving it high? Do you need the signal going into the pin to be low? Or does a device that is connected to the pin need to read low? And permanently LO? Or are you trying to say that you need to invert the signal that appears on the pin? Or invert the signal that the pin puts out?

Comment: Still super unclear. I still don't even know if you want it to be fixed at a permanent voltage level or if you want to invert the signal because this: "*At the moment, RAMN is driven high, but I need it low. In order to drive the RAMN pin low*" doesn't actually tell us. Your wording is just too unclear. Tell us what is actually going on in the circuit, not what you want it to do.

Comment: @DKNguyen hahaha, thanks. What is actually going on in the circuit is as shown in the picture. The signal (from VCCIO) is going into the pin.

Comment: It still isn't making sense. If you want to drive the pin LO permanently just connect it directly to ground. Why is VCCIO relevant at all?

Comment: The circuit was designed that way.. I am trying to understand as well. RAMN is a signal used during booting and I want to drive it low to stall the booting.

Comment: So you are trying to modify a pre-existing circuit and it is wired as posted to fix the HI. But you need it to fix it LO? Okay. You can just short/jumper the pin to GND, most conveniently through the pads that exist for the cap, or you can install a pull-down resistor instead of a jumper. Leaving R225 will require a pull-down resistance no higher than 10K for the resulting voltage divider to still read low. If you remove R225 you can use whatever pull-down resistor value you want. If you short to GND and leave R225 in it will draw some current but otherwise be okay because R225 is so large.

Comment: Yes, yes, that is the right description of my problem :) Your suggestion sounds great! But why is it suggested in this pre-existing circuit to install a capacitor instead of a resistor? that is my question :)

Comment: R225 is a pull-up resistor instead of a direct connection HI so that during debugging and testing you can still apply an external voltage to override the pull-up and drive the line low. Because the resistance chosen was high to reduce current consumption required to to override the line LO, it also means induced noise currents can more easily override the pull-up and and disturb the signal. The capacitor is there as a contingency in case noise was an issue. It stabilizes the voltage and requires large enough noise currents to drain the capacitor to disrupt the voltage on the line.

Comment: Fully understood!! Thank you so much @DKNguyen ♥

Comment: Looks a lot like a cheap power on reset circuit.  Holds RAMN low for some period after VCCIO comes up.

Comment: Please add the details and context you mentioned in the comments to the question. As it is at the moment, it does not make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me suggest that RAMN is a high-impedance input Schmitt trigger. Then R225/C123 provide a significant delay (order of magnitude 1 second) between application of power and part of the circuit starting to function. And in passing, I'll note that it would likely be a very good idea to to provide a reverse-biased diode across R225 to protect the RAMN input when power is removed.

If what you want to do is simply delay booting, the obvious thing to do is increase C123. Adding a switch across C123 is something you can do, but it should have a smallish (let's say, 100 ohms) in series with the switch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgTHPm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

SW1 can be either a mechanical relay or a transistor, but is held closed until some time after power is applied. Especially if you use a mechanical switch, the 100 ohm resistor is needed to protect the contacts from being damaged by discharging the capacitor suddenly.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain a bit more on why you suggest 'to provide a reverse-biased diode across R225 to protect the RAMN input when power is removed'?

Comment: @user7586189 - Let's say the power supply voltage drops to zero in a millisecond. Then the capacitor will still be charged up to very close to VCCIO. Since it will be feeding a circuit which is nominally turned off, the usual current paths may not be appropriate, and you can get a brief surge of current as the capacitor discharges into the IC. This may be a problem, and it may not. A diode serves as an insurance policy by guaranteeing that the capacitor voltage is never more than about 0.7 volts above the actual value of VCCIO.